# Securing REST API Endpoints in Spring Boot with Spring Security: Handling Dynamically Changing Permissions

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, dynamic-permissions

I'm building a REST API using Spring Boot and Spring Security for my application. I have different roles and permissions defined in my system, and I want to secure my API endpoints based on these permissions. However, I have a requirement where the permissions for certain endpoints can change dynamically at runtime, without requiring a server restart or application redeployment.

I've looked into using `@PreAuthorize` and `@PostAuthorize` annotations provided by Spring Security, but they seem to work only with fixed permissions defined in the code or configuration files. I need a solution that allows me to handle dynamically changing permissions for my API endpoints without restarting the application.

Is there a way to achieve this using Spring Boot and Spring Security? How can I implement a solution that allows me to handle dynamically changing permissions for my REST API endpoints in Spring Boot without requiring a server restart or application redeployment?

Answer (score -1):

My Opinion: Change your Security Concept!

1. Use JWT to secure your endpoint!
2. You can create Role-Based Permissions which are Stored in your Datbase and if you make a Request so the Roles will load from your Database -> Which are combined with UserDetailsService from Springboot Library
3. in your RESTController you can then use `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_EDITOR")`

for more Information look at this website:

https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-security-jwt-role-based-authorization